# Jquery not working on IE 10

Tags: jquery

I have some  code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document)
    .ready(function() {
        var count = 0;
        window.onload = function () {
            if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
                history.pushState("back", null, null);
                window.onpopstate = function () {
                    history.pushState('back', null, null);
                    if (count == 1) { window.location = '/Test/OK'; }
                };
            }
        }
        setTimeout(function () { count = 1; }, 200);
    });
```

I just want to call one URL if press back on browser

It is only working on Chrome and Firefox not working on IE10

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` IS the jQuery way of doing a `window.onload`

What you're doing is telling jquery to onload set an onload event.

Remove `window.onload = function () {` and its matching closing brace and you should be good to go. Also you will no longer need the setTimeout which seems like a hack to make the double onload work.

Comment: true, but I was working on the assumption that the code was cut down to the problem area only. OP may have other code in there that makes sense to wrap in doc ready